# In C# Convert.ChangeType(jobj[p.Name].ToString(), p.ParameterType))

Tags: c#, json, web-services

Code for execute service dynamically in C# which has JSON object

```
var jobj = JObject.FromObject(JSON Object);
object instance= new RestServices();

var mi = instance.GetType().GetMethod(jobj["method"].ToString(), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var parameters = mi.GetParameters()
             .Select(p => Convert.ChangeType(jobj[p.Name].ToString(), p.ParameterType))
             .ToArray();

object retval = mi.Invoke(instance, parameters);
```

I have services which have following parameters

```
1.InfoEdit service
{
  "method": "InfoEdit",                   
  "storeId":"1",
  "personalInfo": {
                  "Gender":"test",
                  "FirstName": "test",
                  "CompanyName": "test",
                  "PhoneNumber":"1153646",
                  "NewsLetter":"1"
                  }       
};
2.Login service
{
  "method": "Login",
  "apiSecretKey": "y109m113e122",
  "userName": "test@test.com",
  "password": "test",
  "isGuestCustomerId": 1
}
```

For 1st(**InfoEdit** service) request parameters, I got an error **"Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'DataClass.InfoEditResponse'"**, while for 2nd(**Login** service) request parameters my service called without any hassle.

If anyone have idea about it then please suggest.

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Seems like you need to do extra work converting `service.personalInfo` to actual type. `JObject` just converts it to a `string` (or some kind of keyed collection)

Comment: Try removing the `.ToString()` from your `Select`. Casting operation doesn't seem right because you are converting everything to string and then mapping it to target type. This would be true if type is primitive or structs. For reference type(Custom types) this strategy will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use the  *`ToObject`* method of `JObject`

```
var parameters = mi.GetParameters()
                .Select(p => jobj[p.Name].ToObject(p.ParameterType))
                .ToArray();

object retval = mi.Invoke(instance, parameters);
```